# pagination for webGrid.GetHtml in MVC Razor partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two tabs on my page... For the first tab, I am loading the grid on page load; for the second, on click, I am using `Ajax.ActionLink` to load the grid using a partial View.

I am using `webGrid.GetHtml()` to render the grid with default pagination in both the tabs. The pagination for the First tab is working very smoothly.  But for the grid under the second Tab, if I click on the page number, it will open the entire partial View in a new window with the second page selected.

Any suggestion/solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I searched the whole net but forget to add the attribute ajaxUpdateContainerId for the WebGrid method. It worked like a charm. The page is not refreshing and the pagination is working very smoothly.
The ajaxUpdateContainerId is used to update some tag contents with the refreshed data; provided grid should be loaded using ajax call. So I used a div tag around my grid.gethtml and gave the id of div tag in ajaxUpdateContainerId attribute.

Any other solution will also be accepted....!!!!!

for additional Info 
http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/12/02/reloading-a-razor-webgrid-after-ajax-calls-using-a-partial-view.aspx