# Ajax Pagination with partials in MVC 4 disappearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, pagination

I am using Ajax to populate the partial.

When I click the link on main page, partial correctly populated. If I click another link (list of them), it repopulates.

Inside my partial I have a table of properties. As soon as I click the page button, or header (to order by), the table dissapears. And no longer does the list work to repopulate.

Does anyone know why?

`Properties.cshtml` partial.

```
@model IEnumerable<ns.Models.Property>

@{
    WebGrid table = new WebGrid(ajaxUpdateContainerId: "properties-partial");
    table.Bind(Model);
}

@table.GetHtml()
```

My `main.cshtml` page.

```
<div id="properties-partial">
</div>

    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        item.Title,
            "Properties",
            "Home",
            new { propertyId = item.propertyId},
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "properties-partial" })
```

I've inspected the call being made in firefox, and typed the url directly, and it seems fine (brings up a the correct page of data). It's like it fails to attach to partial after pagination, and from then on breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap your table in its own div inside the partial. and specify that as the `ajaxUpdateContainerID`.

```
@model IEnumerable<ns.Models.Property>

@{
    WebGrid table = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tablediv");

}
<div id="tablediv">
    @table.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem with partials and was able to overcome by doing something like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<ns.Models.Property>

@{
    if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
        var testWebGrid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "testTableDiv");
        <div id="testTableDiv">
           <div id="testGridDiv">
               @testWebGrid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, footerStyle: "pager")
            </div>
            @testWebGrid.Pager()

         </div>
    }
 }
```

jQuery (Remove the the actual paging bar using its class):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pager").remove();
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: It just seems to remove my table like before. Its definately effecting the partial, but blanks it. and makes it unusable for anything else. +1 for trying

Comment: Better googling, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226000/pagination-for-webgrid-gethtml-in-mvc-razor-partial-view He suggests to put a div around `@table.GetHtml()` (inside the partial and using ajaxUpdateContainerId). Has done the trick :)